# SQL- preserve order from 'IN' clause and return null for non matching clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table `Person` with columns `id`, `name`, and `phone`. I want to fetch all records matching a list of pairs of names and phone numbers while preserving the order from the 'IN' clause and returning `null` or any default value for the mismatching clause.

For instance, if the `Person` table has the following records:

| id | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 1234 |
| 2 | Name2 | 2345 |
| 3 | Name3 | 4532 |

I want the query to return the ids of people matching pairs of names and phone numbers.
When queried with
`('Name2', 2345), ('NonExistingName', 34543), ('Name1', 1234)` should return a list `[2, <null or a default value>, 1]`

I am aware that I can use `IN` clause to find the matching rows,

```
SELECT id
FROM Person
WHERE (name, phone) in (('Name2', 2345),
                        ('NonExistingName', 34543),
                        ('Name1', 1234));
```

however, this alone doesn't fulfill what I want. The rows returned do not preserve the order and do not allow me to add a default value for nonexisting ids.

Comment: Put your IN values in a table. LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Also: which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational databases explicitly disclaim any responsibility to ever preserve order unless you specify an ORDER BY clause. Therefore you will need to include the order information as part of the data in a way where you can reference it in the ORDER BY clause.

For example:

```
WITH source AS (
    SELECT 'Name2' Name, 2345 Phone, 0 Ordinal
    UNION
    SELECT 'NonExistingName', 34543, 1
    UNION
    SELECT 'Name1', 1234, 2
)
SELECT p.id
FROM source s 
LEFT JOIN Person p ON s.Name = p.Name and s.Phone = p.Phone
ORDER BY s.Ordinal
```

Or:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM (VALUES 
    ROW ('Name2', 2345, 0),
    ROW ('NonExistingName', 34543, 1),
    ROW ('Name1', 1234, 2)
) s 
LEFT JOIN Person p ON s.column_0 = p.Name and s.column_1 = p.Phone
ORDER BY s.column_2
```

Comment: One can also use the [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) in MySQL 8.0 to create an instance of an ad hoc table.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's why I asked which version :) VALUES requires 8.0.19 (2020) where the CTE only requires 8.0.1 (2017) -- Though I admit I had to look up those exact versions and dates, I remembered several times in recent years where I had to do this instead of VALUES on a MySQL environment. At least we're getting to the point where assuming 8.0 instead of 5.7 (or worse) is reasonable.

Comment: Yes, and we should also assume that if folks use 8.0.x, there's no reason that they can't upgrade at least to 8.0.19 (released January 2020).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful. We are currently on 5.7 (AWS Aurora 2.10.2) but plan to upgrade soon to 8.0.23 (Aurora 2.02.2) as 5.7 is approaching EOL in October 2023. I am going to have to push for an early upgrade just to have CTE :)

Comment: You should read this: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/05/04/whats-up-with-mysql/ (start with the 2nd paragraph)